# Why do you drive a car on parkway, and park a car at driveway?

Tags: word-usage

Why?

Usually, we always drive a car on the road, often the road's called "**park**way". Which seems to be opposite of driving.
 On the other hand, we park a car at parking lot or "**drive**way". And again, which seems to be opposite of parking.

Why can we just drive a car on the driveway and park a car at parkway? Why is it reversed? What is the origin of this (seems to be) weird usage?

Comment: To someone who close voted this question... What kind of research or context do you want? Surely I could (or should) have linked at least oxford, but I thought the meaning was widely-known. Maybe my searching skills are mediocre so I couldn't find why this "reverse" is happening (all I could find was joke about this question and not concrete answer). For context... I think I've already given as much context I could think of.

Comment: You could have looked at the dictionary definitions or Wikipedia, which has fairly good explanations of the terms.

Comment: **park a car in a driveway**. Not at. driveways and parkways are completely unrelated. You need to look them up. There is no reversal. park is a place with trees and plants.

Comment: Because English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names are just ironic coincidences.

A parkway is a highway that goes by or through **a park** or natural landscape. The name has nothing to do with parking a car, other than the etymological connection that Kate points out in the comment.

A driveway is the lane you **drive through** to get to your garage. It's a coincidence that people so often park in them now.

Comment: The connection with parking a car is a complicated one. A park was originally an enclosed area of land round a big country house; the meaning evolved into a landscaped area for the public to enjoy, but another meaning was an enclosed area used for a particular purpose. An area for storing vehicles and cannon was called an _artillery park_, so in the 20th century we get the British term _car park_ and the verb _to park [something]_.

Comment: "to put (a vehicle) in a certain place" is first recorded 1844. That's from here: https://etymology.en-academic.com/26676/park